# Como inserir dados em um vetor membro de uma struct?

Tags: c++, string, struct, vector, stl

Estou tentando construir uma estrutura composta por membros que não são mais do que strings. O 4º membro é um vetor de strings, já que ele precisa guardar mais de uma informacao.

Uma vez feito isso eu declaro eu vetor de estruturas. Quando vou inserir os dados dentro desse
vetor de estruturas, o compilador acusa que está faltando uma expressão primária antes de "{". Detalhe que quando insiro os dados dentro do vetor, excluindo o membro vetor string da estrutura, o programa funciona normalmente.

segue o código:

```
struct Estrutura{
  std::string x;
  std::string y;
  std::string z;
  std::vector <std::string> result;
};

std::vector <Estrutura> vec_estrutura;

int main(){

  vec_estrutura.push_back(Estrutura{"lero", "lero", "lero", Estrutura.result.push_back("la", "li", "ho")});

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você está tentando fazer é inicializar a sua estrutura com listas de inicialização (*initialization lists*) mas o que você está realmente fazendo é violando regras da linguagem.

Para inicializar uma estrutura que contém outra estrutura (ou vetor) você deve passar listas (de inicialização) dentro de listas. No caso, segue a correção:

```cpp
int main() {
    vec_estrutura.push_back(Estrutura{
            "lero",
            "lero",
            "lero",
            { "la", "li", "ho" }
        });

    return 0;
}
```

Percebe que o quarto elemento da lista de inicialização é uma outra lista de inicialização para inicializar o `vector`? Simples, não?

Comment: Obrigado amigo. realmente tinha a impressão de estar cometendo um erro fundamental